# MethodMissingException in F# user code; how?

Tags: .net, f#, .net-core

I've written a couple of simplistic F# projects.  Let's call them `Console` and `Library`.

`Console` is a very simple console application targeting `netcoreapp2.0`.  Here's the project file `Console.fsproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="FSharp.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="../Library/Library.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The source, `Program.fs`:

```
open System
open Library

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let result = Stats.ema 0.0 [3.7; 8.9]
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Now, `Library.fsproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="FSharp.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Library.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and `Library.fs`:

```
module Library.Stats

let ema (prevEma:float) (values:float list) =
    0.0
```

I can restore both projects just fine (using nuget.org only), and building works fine too:

```
C:\Users\ben\proj\scratch
λ  dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.117.23532
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Library -> C:\Users\ben\proj\scratch\src\Library\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Library.dll
  Console -> C:\Users\ben\proj\scratch\src\Console\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Console.dll
```

However, at runtime the program throws a `MissingMethodException`:

```
C:\Users\ben\proj\scratch\src\Console
λ  dotnet run

Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Double Library.Stats.ema(Double, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<Double>)'.
   at Program.main(String[] argv)
```

Here's my `dotnet --info`:

```
C:\Users\ben\proj\scratch\src\Console
λ  dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0-preview1-005977)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0-preview1-005977
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  414cab8a0b

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0-preview1-005977\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0-preview1-002111-00
  Build    : 1ff021936263d492539399688f46fd3827169983
```

What is causing this?

Update:

As might be seen in the comments, I found that the conflicting references were to `System.Runtime` rather than to `FSharp.Core`, and that references is added somewhere in the SDK or tooling.

Still having not run down a good answer to this, I've opened an issue on the [dotnet/netcorecli-fsc](https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/issues/117) repository.

Comment: Wrong version of `FSharp.Core.dll` is present at runtime.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I saw that there are a number of GitHub issues related to that, but in all those cases, the missing methods are actually in some version of `FSharp.Core`.  It seems different to me that this is failing to find a method in user code.

Comment: It's the same reason. Your method declares a parameter of type that comes from `FSharp.Core.dll` version x, and the consuming code is looking for a method that has a parameter coming from `FSharp.Core.dll` version y. Since the type of parameter doesn't match, it's not considered the same method. Hence, "method not found".

Comment: @FyodorSoikin ok - that makes sense, but it looks like the version loaded at runtime is the same used at compile-time (i.e., what's in `Console`'s `project.assets.json` shows the `netstandard1.6` target of `FSharp.Core` 4.1.7, and the debugger shows the same file loaded when I try to run it under the debugger.  How do I figure out which version it wants?

Comment: Open both compiled binaries in ILSpy and see which version they reference.

Comment: Both reference 4.4.1.0, which is the version represented in the 4.1.7 nupkg.

Comment: Ah, it looks like the `System.Runtime` reference is conflicting, not `FSharp.Core`